# Leap Seconds in OS X

Tags: macos, time

A leap second was recently added on June 30, 2015 23:59:60 UTC.

How are leap seconds implemented on OS X (specifically Yosemite)?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? (Basically - what makes you think leap second processing is even implemented? Worse, several standards for converting and measuring time on computers actually forbid accounting for leap seconds. (ntp, IEEE Std 1003.1-1988 (``POSIX.1'') legislates that a time_t value of 536457599 shall correspond to "Wed Dec 31 23:59:59 GMT 1986."  This effectively implies that POSIX time_t's cannot include leap seconds and, therefore, that the system time must be adjusted as each leap occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X and iOS use ntp-like software daemons to poll for and periodically adjust internal clocks based on external time sources.

A leap second arrives as an external correction similar to how each hardware clock corrects minor (or major) skews and inaccuracies periodically.

OS X ships with perl modules to accurately determine if a leap second is coming or has come, but internally it's not handled like leap years where the system knows in advance and automatically adjusts it's internal clock without needing to be corrected from an external time keeping source.

- https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=leap%20second
- Perl module [LeapSecond](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/DateTime__LeapSecond.3pm.html)
- [time2posix](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/time2posix.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/time2posix) man page